# How to convert result of df.value_counts() to standard dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm counting based on 2 columns `default` and `education`. The output is

```
default  education
0        2            10700
         1             8549
         3             3680
1        2             3330
         1             2036
         3             1237
0        5              262
         4              116
         6               43
1        5               18
0        0               14
1        6                8
         4                7
dtype: int64
```

Could you please explain how to fill in the empty rows of column `default`?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/dataset.csv')
df.rename(columns = {'default payment next month': 'default'}, inplace = True)
df.columns = list(map(str.lower, df.columns))
df.value_counts(subset=['default', 'education'])
```

Comment: `df.value_counts(subset=['default', 'education']).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post @Anurag Dabas's answer here to remove question from unanswered list.

> `df.value_counts(subset=['default', 'education']).reset_index()`